# How to get model attribute linked with foreign key in Flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have created two models in Flask-Sqlalchemy. These models are `Tickets` and `Namespace`. Both models are connect with a foreign key. I also created marshmallow-sqlalchemy `ModelSchema` definitions to use in a RESTful API.

```
class Ticket(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    namespace = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('namespace.id'), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    status = db.Column(db.String)
    severity = db.Column(db.String)


class TicketSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        include_fk = True
```

```
class Namespace(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)


class NamespaceSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Namespace
```

In my view I am trying to filter all tickets by given *namespace*. This is my query:

```
@app.route("/<string:name>", methods=["GET"])
def get_tickets_by_namespace(name):

    tickets_query = Ticket.query.join(Namespace).filter(Namespace.name == name)
    result = TicketSchema(many=True).dump(tickets_query).data

    return jsonify({"tickets": result})
```

How do I access the `name` attribute from the `Namespace` model while joining and filtering two models?

When I enter the above URL using `/aa`, I only get `namespace_id`, I would like to also see the name of namespace:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "description": "xcv",
      "id": 1,
      "namespace": 1,
      "severity": "xcvbn",
      "status": "xcvb",
      "title": "xc"
    },
    {
      "description": "xcv",
      "id": 3,
      "namespace": 1,
      "severity": "xcvbnb",
      "status": "axcvb",
      "title": "axcb"
    },
    {
      "description": "xcv",
      "id": 4,
      "namespace": 1,
      "severity": "bnb",
      "status": "axcvb",
      "title": "aaaxcb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please [don' use images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Clear, thank You and sorry for the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `include_fk`, you want to give your models a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationships.html):

```
class Ticket(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    namespace_id = db.Column(
        'namespace',
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('namespace.id'),
        nullable=False
    )
    namespace = db.relationship("Namespace", backref="tickets")

    title = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    status = db.Column(db.String)
    severity = db.Column(db.String)
```

Relationships are automatically included, but their default field still only serialised the foreign keys.

Make sure to only define marshmallow-sqlalchemy models *after* all your SQLAlchemy models have loaded, as creating models will trigger a mapping configuration run (where string expressions such as the `"Namespace"` string in the `db.relationship()` call) are resolved. You can't create a Marshmallow model of the `Ticket` model until the `Namespace` model also has been created.

Next, [use a `Nested()` field](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nesting.html) to pull in the `Namespace` attributes you want:

```
class TicketSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket

    # don't include 'tickets' when including a namespace schema.
    # you can also put this on the NestedSchema model.
    namespace = ma.Nested("NamespaceSchema", exclude=("tickets",))
```

In the above example the `exclude=("tickets",)` argument is needed to avoid the `tickets` relationship on the `Namespace` object to also be reflected in the resulting JSON (it'll contain only foreign keys, Marshmallow realises it already serialised the tickets). You can also add the `exclude` to the `NamespaceSchema` model `Meta`, but then *all* use of that schema will exclude the `tickets` field.

With the above changes, your route outputs:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "description": "xcv",
      "id": 1,
      "namespace": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aa"
      },
      "severity": "xcvbn",
      "status": "xcvb",
      "title": "xc"
    },
    {
      "description": "xcv",
      "id": 3,
      "namespace": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aa"
      },
      "severity": "xcvbnb",
      "status": "axcvb",
      "title": "axcb"
    },
    {
      "description": "xcv",
      "id": 4,
      "namespace": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aa"
      },
      "severity": "bnb",
      "status": "axcvb",
      "title": "aaaxcb"
    }
  ]
}
```